# Adding watch to directive inner element.val() even without ngModel

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, jqlite

```
---html---
<input-wrap>
<input type="text"/>
</input-wrap>

---js---
myModule.directive('inputWrap',function(){
   return{
       restrict: 'E',
       priority: 0,
       link: function(scope,element,attr){
           var myInput = element.find('input');
           scope.$watch(myInput.val(),function(val){
                 console.log('recipe is now:'+val);
           });
       }
   }
});
```

I want to do this even without the help of on('change') and on('input')
because the value is sometimes modified by the plugin I used, and it doesn't fire onChange and onInput events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your watcher like :

```
myModule.directive('inputWrap',function(){
return{
   restrict: 'E',
   priority: 0,
   link: function(scope,element,attr){
       var myInput = element.find('input');
       scope.$watch(function() { return myInput.val() },function(val){
             console.log('recipe is now:'+val);
       });
   }
 }
});
```

Comment: thank you so much, one last question I thought $watch was suppose to watch like this $watch('variablename',handler())? Why does your solution still work even without the string representation of the variable name?

Comment: You can provide two things to $watch :
 - A string that represent a variable in scope. The callback will be called when value of variable change in scope.
 - A function. Will be called on each digest phase. This method doesn't need to have any representation into scope. But performance can be bad because the function is called many times.